# Dynamically Generate Form Row With Select Populated From Database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Here's my dilema. In Laravel, I'm passing `inspections` to the view like so:

```
$inspections = Inspection::where("status", "!=", "started")->get();
return View::make('process')->with("inspections", $inspections);
```

Inspections contains a list of all the Inspections that are passed the started stage. In the view, I'm creating a form to process these Inspections like so:

```
<tr id="row_0" data-row="0">
  <td>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="inspection[0]">
      <option value=""></option>
      @foreach($inspections AS $inspection)
      <option value="{{ $inspection->id }}">{{ $inspection->submission_number }} - {{ $inspection->policy_number }} - {{ $inspection->location_address }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="received[0]" value="yes" >Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="received[0]" value="no" >No</label></td>
  <td><label class="radio-inline"><input id="i_on_0" type="radio" name="invoiced[0]" value="yes" onclick="toggleInvoice(this);" data-row="0"/>Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input id="i_off_0" type="radio" name="invoiced[0]" value="no" onclick="toggleInvoice(this);" data-row="0"/>No</label></td>
  <input type="hidden" id="in_0" name="invoice_number[0]" disabled/>
  <td><input type="text" id="ia_0" name="invoice_amount[0]" class="form-control input-sm" disabled/></td>
  <td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="p_on_0" name="paid[0]" value="yes" disabled/>Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="p_off_0" name="paid[0]" value="no" disabled/>No</label></td>
</tr>
```

Which creates the following:

[image: Capture]

This is fine and dandy, but I have no idea how to append another row to this table and **still display the value of each option**. Right now, I have my + button call the following function in Javascript:

```
function appendProcessingRow(){
  var current_row = $("#processing_table tr:last").attr("data-row");
  var content = '<tr id="row_' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '" data-row="' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '"><td><input type="text" name="policy_number[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" class="form-control input-sm"/></td><td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="received[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="yes">Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="received[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="no"> No</label></td><td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="invoiced[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="yes" onclick="toggleInvoice(this);" data-row="' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '"/> Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="invoiced[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="no" onclick="toggleInvoice(this);" data-row="' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '"/> No</label></td><input type="hidden" id="in_' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '" name="invoice_number[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" disabled/>><td><input type="text" id="ia_' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '" name="invoice_amount[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" class="form-control input-sm" disabled/></td><td><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="p_on_' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '" name="paid[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="yes" disabled/> Yes</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" id="p_off_' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + '" name="paid[' + (parseInt(current_row) + 1) + ']" value="no" disabled/> No</label></td></tr>';
  $('#processing_table > tbody:last').append(content);
}
```

Which works, but creates an `<input>` tag instead of the select option. See the following:

[image: Capture2]

My question, how would I got about creating the same row layout in Javascript, keeping in mind that the select is generated by `@foreach` in Laravel? Tried putting the:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="inspection[0]">
  <option value=""></option>
  @foreach($inspections AS $inspection)
  <option value="{{ $inspection->id }}">{{ $inspection->submission_number }} - {{ $inspection->policy_number }} - {{ $inspection->location_address }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Inside the Javascript `appendProcessingRow()` And it "worked" to an extent, but the values aren't there:

[image: Capture3]

So, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance, sorry for the long post.

Comment: I suppose it is possible that there is now row in the table and you need to be able to add one by the click of "+"?

Comment: Yes, that's the current functionality. Pressing "+" creates the 2nd image (3rd after modified the code). Adding/Removing rows via Javascript works perfectly, but the `select` element doesn't get populated properly.

Comment: Sorry typo.. I meant to ask if it is possible that there aren't any rows in the table? (because otherwise "cloning" the row would be an option)

Comment: There is always 1 hardcoded `row[0]` in the table, which can't be removed.

Comment: I see... Writing an answer...

Comment: Ok. I think I know what you mean by cloning it; serializing the `<tr>` element to a JSON object and using that in the function. Which works, but I don't want an exact replica, I'd prefer an empty row.

Comment: You'll see. Just give me a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going "full ajax" to fetch the options from the server I think cloning the existing row is the easiest approach.

```
function appendProcessingRow(){
    var lastRow = $("#processing_table tr:last");
    var newRow = lastRow.clone();
    var newId = parseInt(lastRow.data('row'))+1;
    newRow.data('row', newId);
    newRow.prop('id', newId);
    newRow.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // reset other inputs in a similar fashion

    lastRow.after(newRow);
}
```

Also about your input names... You should be able to just leave them all like `policy_number[]` without an index. It will automatically put the values in an array (in the order they appear in the html)

Comment: Yup. That looks pretty simple. And saves having to maintain the stupidly long `var content = ...` line. I'll implement this. I did come up with a `full ajax` solution while you were writing this, but this is much more elegant. Thanks for the help Lukas!

Comment: Oh also, my naming conventions `policy_number[0]` is redundant for indexed arrays, but necessary for associative ones, so I agree I won't need it in this case.

Comment: You're welcome. also note that e.g. for radio buttons you don't have to reset every single one on its own. You can just do `$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false)` for all of them